# How to create new reference to existing array without copying the array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, reference, pipe

Is it possible to create a new reference to an array without going through the array? 
My problem is that I have a pure angular pipe which doesn't detect push/pop changes. I would like to avoid solutions like this:

```
this.array = this.array.filter(e=>true)
```

Which adds complexity just to update reference.
I have tried first thing that came to my head but it doesn't work (pipe doesn't detect any changes) and I am not familiar with js/ts enough to know why it didn't work.

```
const newRef = this.array;
this.array = null;
this.array = newRef
```

I have pipe which gets array of objects and array of filters and returns array of filtered objects.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'eventFilter'
})
export class EventFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(events: EventDtos[], filters:Filter[]): any {
     //return filtered events
  }
```

Pipe useage:

```
<div  class="event" *ngFor="let event of events  | eventFilter:filters">
   html stuff
</div>
```

After pushing/poping filter from `filters`, pipe's transform isn't called so I am using this code to force `transform` call:

```
this.filters = this.filters.filter(e=>true)
```

But at this point I don't know which one is faster, this method or impure pipe. So Ideally I would like to leave pure pipe and update `filters` reference without adding complexity

Comment: Your sample at the end should create a reference to the array.  Can you expand on what pipe you were using and why/how it didn't work?

Comment: @JeffryHouser I have added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend you to use impure pipe, it will be executed and filter events on every change detection, and there may be hundreds of change detections per second.

What about your attempt of the reference changing, actually it doesn't change the reference, you just change a variable, which contains the reference:

```js
const newRef = this.array; // newRef references the array
this.array = null;
this.array = newRef // this.array references the same array, nothing is changed
```

So, copying of the array, as you did, is better solution, but there are simpler ways:

```js
this.array = [...this.array];
// or
this.array = this.array.slice();
```

Another solution is to use a [Subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/subject.html) and [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). In this case there is no need to copy the array. If the array is big, or filters are often changed, it may be the preferred way:

```js
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
    readonly filters$ = new BehaviourValue<Filter>([]);

    ...
    addFilter(filter: Filter): void {
        this.filters$.value.push(filter);
        this.filters$.next(this.filters$.value);
    }
}
```

```html
<div  class="event" *ngFor="let event of events | eventFilter:(filters$ | async)">
   html stuff
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you probably looking for a impure pipe in Angular? In this way, your pipe is automatically update for every input changes. You can find more information on the official guide https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes

Comment: Ideally I would like to leave pure pipe as it is faster